# The Cluster ID XXXXXXXXXXXX doesn't match stored clusterId Some

Tags: apache-kafka

On two nodes Kafka cluster after restart one node I have get error:

```
ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID hJGLXQwERc2rTXI_dWLwcg doesn't match stored clusterId Some(9VcFGDwSfke5JWuzA6f9mw) in meta.properties. The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:223)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

Where *hJGLXQwERc2rTXI_dWLwcg* - ID of worked cluster from meta.properties

*9VcFGDwSfke5JWuzA6f9mw* - new generated ID.

Kafka version 3.0.0

On Node1 :

**server.properties**:

```
broker.id=1
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://loc-kafka1:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/opt/kafka/logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=loc-kafka1:2181, loc-kafka2:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
compression.type=gzip
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
super.users=User:admin
sasl.jaas.config=/opt/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf
delete.topic.enable=true
```

**zookeeper.properties**

```
dataDir=/opt/kafka/zookeeper/data
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=10
admin.enableServer=false
server1=loc-kafka1:2888:3888
server2=loc-kafka2:2888:3888
```

On Node2 the same config except broker.id=2 and myid file in dataDir.

All information what I can find sad : you should place log.dirs and dataDir not in /tmp folder. And all will done. But it's not like that.
One solution is clear log.dirs and dataDir folders allow this node connect to cluster. But this doesn't seem good solution.

If I just delete meta.properties, new cluster.id is plased in it and node don't connect to cluster.  At the same time, in server.logs, the following lines show that the node is connecting to another cluster node:

```
INFO Opening socket connection to server loc-kafka1/10.1.1.3:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
INFO SASL config status: Will attempt to SASL-authenticate using Login Context section 'Client' (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: loc-kafka2/10.1.1.4:38672, server: loc-kafka1/10.1.1.3:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
INFO Session establishment complete on server loc-kafka1/10.0.0.3:3001, session id = 0x100000043bb0006, negotiated timeout = 18000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

What I can do to fix it?

Comment: Not storing data in /tmp doesn't magically "fix" any id issues. It'll simply prevent you from losing everything if the server machine gets restarted. Seems like part of the problem is that you're only running two Zookeepers. You need an odd number

Comment: I tried to raise the 3rd kafka node - the same result. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Zookepeper, not Kafka. But, how are you running the nodes?

Comment: Start/Stop from here : https://ledinhcuong99.medium.com/start-kafka-service-failed-on-ubuntu-e6170dbe235a

Comment: Did you edit `/etc/hosts` at any point? And what exactly is running on port 3001? That is not a Kafka or Zookeeper port... In your logs, I see `server: loc-kafka1/10.1.1.3` and `loc-kafka1/10.0.0.3:3001`, indicating that `loc-kafka1` has two different addresses

Comment: Yes а change port 2181 to 3001 in all configs. And loc-kafka1/loc-kafka2 present in /etc/hosts on all hosts

Comment: Okay, but you really shouldn't touch /etc/hosts (and seems you put two different addresses for the kafka1 machine) and the ports really should not need changed either. Sounds to me like you started everything with default configs, which generated some IDs and stored IP/host/port information in Zookeeper, then you decided to modify everything to change something related to networking, and now you're getting conflicts? Is that correct? If so, yes, wiping all the data directories and starting over is one solution.

Comment: Ok. For those who encounter this error: start zookeepr first, then start kafka. Not vice versa. And everything works.

Comment: 1) Feel free to put that as an answer below rather than comment 2) This should be obvious and you'd get a different error if Kafka is started without Zookeeper